# Nautilus file arrangment

Tags: fedora, upgrade, nautilus

I don't know if it is a bug or there is a settings I missed, but after the upgrade to Fedora 27 from 26, some folders in nautilus showing weird arrangement like this.

[image]

Comment: Look in the Nautilus preferences for an "experimental" interface and see if it's enabled.

Comment: No, It's not enabled. But it seems logging-in using Wayland fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this is because of buggy pango library used in text rendering. To solve this just downgrade pango library to version 1.40.12.1.

```
sudo dnf downgrade pango-1.40.12-1.fc27.x86_64 pango-1.40.12-1.fc27.i686
```

I hope this will solve your problem.